# Changing a regular object into a working function. TypeError: not a function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Today I've been experimenting with a function prototype and I've tried to change a regular object into a working function.
What I've tried so far is something like that:

```
const fn = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(fn, Function.prototype);
Function.prototype.constructor.call(fn, 'console.log("function here!")');

fn(); // Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function
```

Any idea how it might have been doable?
Cheers!

Comment: What do you expect the object to do? It's not a function, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I expect it to be callable. Since functions are objects inheriting from Function.prototype, I thought it might be possible.